# Databricks: "Numba needs NumPy 1.22" when updating numpy

Tags: python, azure-databricks

I'm using Azure Databricks with Python.  Among other things, I'm using the umap and numpy modules.  When I try `import umap.umap_ as umap`, I get this error:

ImportError: Numba needs NumPy 1.22 or greater. Got NumPy 1.21.

Ok, so just update numpy, right?  I ran `!{sys.executable} -m pip install numpy --upgrade` and it worked.  Numpy now shows version in the module explorer:

[image: Module explorer screenshot - numpy]

But when I try the umap import again I get the same error as before, telling me it needs 1.22+.  That requirement is met, although it seems like the 1.26 version is not being loaded.  I have tried getting the proper version loaded using this:

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.require("numpy==1.26.0")
import numpy as np
```

Still no luck.  That gives:

```
VersionConflict: (numpy 1.21.5 (/databricks/python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages), Requirement.parse('numpy==1.26.0'))
```

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes even though you install `numpy==1.26.0` it still shows you `numpy==1.21.5`.

[image]

Actually, numba  requires numpy<1.26,>1.22.

So install `numpy==1.24.0` in cluster libraries configuration and re-attach the notebook.

[image]

Now you will get correct numpy module and you can import `umap` successfully.

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this.  I'm quite new to Databricks, and Azure in general, so this was very informative.  I apologize for not responding sooner... applying this solution revealed a couple of other problems, which are also fixed.  Thanks again.